# what's the associated html to load images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to load images from my images directory.

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
$("<img>", {
    "src": "url.php...",
    "load": function() {
        alert("loaded!");
        $("#foo").attr("src", "url.php...");
    }
});​
```

For the html, I'm not sure how to get started.  I tried this: `<img id="foo" src="$('#img').attr('src');">`, but I'm thinking I'm not escaping html properly.

Comment: what is in url.php??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set response data from server to image source like this

Js

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url.php"
}).done(function( data ) {
    $("#img").attr("src", data );
  });
```

PHP (url.php)

```
echo '/images/1.jpg';
```